# Removing artifact from PDF figure in LaTeX, compiled with pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, floats

I am working on a document in LaTeX, and when inserting pdf figures I get a weird black line down the right side.  This is not present in the original pdfs (I've checked).  I thought it might be some scaling issue, since several of my figures are large and I have to scale them smaller than actual size in LaTeX, but it also appears in this figure, which is actual size.
My code for the figure is:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[height = 9.6cm]{"testschema"}
\caption{Database Schema for test case, simulating results from a test suite}
\label{fig:schematest}
\end{figure}
```

And the output after compiling with pdflatex is:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This stems from an overfull `\hbox` as the image is too wide to fit within the margins. If you include the image inside a frame

```
% In the document preamble to show the text block visually
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}
  \fbox{\includegraphics[height = 9.6cm]{testschema}}
  ...
\end{figure}
```

you'll see it's wider than the text block. This may be due to padding/white space surrounding the actual image (the bounding box is not tight enough). The rule drawn in the margin is usually not visible with only a "Warning: Overfull `\hbox` found..." in the `.log`. You can remove this rule by setting the width of `\overfullrule` to `0pt`:

```
\setlength{\overfullrule}{0pt}
```

Other alternatives:

- run the PDF image through the [`pdfcrop`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop) Perl script to see if it can remove the excess white space;
- scale the image using `width` (to, say, `\linewidth`) rather than `height`;
- use the `bb=<bbllx> <bblly> <bburx> <bbury>` key-value (since you're using [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)) to set the `l`ower-`l`eft `x`,`y` and `u`pper `r`ight `x`,`y` `b`ounding `b`ox coordinates to trim the image yourself.